# ld: file not found: elf_i386 error on Mac Terminal

Tags: gcc, terminal, linker-errors, gnu, elf

when i run a command in terminal (Using El Capitan)

```
ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```

It shows the following error :

```
ld: warning: option -m is obsolete and being ignored
ld: file not found: elf_i386
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when i run a command in terminal

You are trying to link some kind of kernel using `ld` directly. This is actually one of very few cases where using `ld` directly is appropriate.

However, the command line arguments you give to `ld` assume that you are using GNU-ld (you may have copied them from a Linux tutorial), but you are *not* using GNU-ld, you are using MacOS native linker, which doesn't understand these arguments.

> Can anybody help me with this?

Please ask a separate question, along the lines of "I am trying to build XXX on MacOS, following tutorial YYY, and don't understand how to adjust this Linux command to Mac OS".

Note that it may not be possible to build XXX on MacOS at all. In particular, the [ld manpage](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/ld.1.html) does not mention `ELF` as possible output, so if your "build XXX" goal includes building an ELF kernel, you'll likely need to build a cross-linker (a GNU-ld linker which runs on Mac OS (i.e. hosted on Mac OS), but produces code for `ELF` target.

Comment: So what do you think i should do?
I even tried to add elf_i386 manually to the folder where rest of the gcc files are there.
but the only problem is coming in the " ld " command though the nasm and gcc are working just fine.

@employed-russian